how to stay logged in if creating a new scenario on cypress bdd testing
import { Given, When, Then, DataTable } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import CheckoutPage from "../../e2e/pages/CheckoutPage";

const checkoutPage = new CheckoutPage()


beforeEach( () => {
  cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/', { timeout: 60000});
});
  
Given('I successfully enters the all items page', () => {
  cy.Login("standard_user", "secret_sauce")
});
  
When ('I clicks the add to cart button and delete to cart remove button', () => {
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSaucelabsBackpack()
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSauceLabsBikeLigh()
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSauceLabsBoltTShirt()
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSauceLabsFleeceJacket()
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSauceLabsOnesie()
    checkoutPage.clickOnARemoveSauceLabsBikeLigh()
    checkoutPage.ClickOnButtonCart()
})
Then ('item successfully entered the cart button', () => {
    checkoutPage.verifySuccessEnterPageYourCart()
})

Given ('I successfully enters the cart page', () => {
    checkoutPage.verifySuccessEnterPageYourCart()
})
When('I delete a selected item and reselect the item on the product page', () => {
    checkoutPage.clickOnRemoveSaucelabsBackpack()
    checkoutPage.clickOnAddToCartSaucelabsBackpack()
    checkoutPage.ClickOnButtonCart()
    checkoutPage.clickOnCheckout()
})
Then('I successfully entered your information page', () => {
    checkoutPage.verifySuccessEnterPageYourInformation()
})

in the checkoutstep section if I create a new scenario it always fails because I have to re-login
I've tried using cy.session but it still doesn't work.
please help me
